# Dynamic allocate/free structure with embedding lock in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, locking, linux-device-driver

I want to free a structure with spin_lock is embedded.

scenario is as follows:

I have two functions

```
f1 () {
*****************
    spin_lock_irqsave(&my_obj_ptr->my_lock, flags)
      ....
      .... ........................................ here f2 is called                                            
    spin_lock_irqstore(&my_obj_ptr->my_lock, flags)
*******************
    kfree(my_obj_ptr) 
}
```

and f2 has similar content with f1.

when f2 is called my_lock is being used, f2 must busy waiting.
however, when f2 is entering the critical section, my_obj_ptr is free. 
So kernel crash...

What I think now is adding a ref_count variable in struct my_obj

before spin_lock_irqsave  => ref_count++

after  spin_lock_irqstore => ref_count--

And before free, check the ref_count variable.

And it seems no crash now.

I just wonder will there be corner cases, I don't consider? 
Or there is any much better way to handle this problem?

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After tracing the linux-source code, I found a example of solving this kind of problem.

The correct way is to split the spin_lock from the target freeing structure, so that it will not be destroyed after target freeing object is destroyed.

And check if the target free object is NULL or not in the lock protected region, so that you'll not free it again.

So the sample code may be as follows:

```
f1 () {
    //Notice that my_lock is not in the structure my_obj any more
    spin_lock_irqsave(my_lock, flags)
    .....

    //check if my_obj_ptr is NULL or not
    //And kfree must be done in the lock protected region
    //otherwise it will not be safe
    if (my_obj_ptr != NULL) 
        kfree(my_obj_ptr)

    ......
    spin_lock_irqstore(my_lock, flags)
}
```