# Why doesn't sk_buff have spin_lock or mutex

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Just don't understand why does not the structure sk_buff have the spin_lock or mutex variable.

Gut feeling is there may be multiple threads want to access skb?

I know it has "users" variable for reference counts and when doing free, kfree_skb will check the users variable, but that doesn't protect the other consistency of other data in this struct, right?

Any tips will be appreciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why should multiple threads want to access a *skb*?

Usually are filled by one and enqueued in a fifo list (example the network driver) and then dequeued by another one (example the receiving user process), multiple threads may want to access the list but concurrency is already handled at *list level*.

Obviously locks should be avoided if not necessary, the *skb* code is probably one of the most used in every day usage (fifo/pipes and network, kernel ipc?), if there is a concurrency bug should reveal itself very soon.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Since I see the users variable, so that variable means "how many readers are using this skb now"?

Comment: Actually I just want to try the method used in skb to solve my problem at this thread   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494099/dynamic-allocate-free-structure-with-embedding-lock-in-linux-kernel

Comment: @AnakinTung, I see, so you splitted the struct from the data and can free it without crash but then have a concurrency problem modifying the data?

Comment: Actually I see the code in arch/um/drivers/net_kern.c. You can refer the function update_drop_skb in that source file. There will be no concurrency problem for modifying the data, since the spin_lock is protecting.